# Face recognition webpage

Tags: vb.net, ftp, arduino, host, face-recognition

I'm working on a project that recognizes faces.

The idea of the project is as follows:

I have an arduino connected with a GSM/GPRS shield. This gives the arduino the ability to connect to the internet. I have also connected a special shield for a camera.

Now I managed to take photos from the camera and upload them using FTP to a webhost.

The problem is that I won't the web host to be able to recognize the face with a pre-saved SQL  database and reply via FTP to the arduino with the name of the person recognized in a Text file.
Of course for that matter, I have SD card with it's shield connected to the arduino.

I would love to hear your opinions on how will that work if it's possible in the first place?

I've seen so far some application fourms done in VB to do Face recognition. Is there a way to upload these fourms -btw they are regular fourm not ASP.net - to the host and somehow use it to do the FR?

Thanks,
Adel A. Bibi

Comment: Facial recognition is a fairly complex task.  You are in the world of neural nets.  It isn't just taking a picture and comparing pixel by pixel - if you do that, the angle of your face, background etc has to be exactly the same.  First you have to work out where the face is.  Then you need to pick out the points of interest, like the eye separation and work it out relative to what you have in the database.

Comment: If I guaranteed that the face has to be covering the total image. No backgrounds are available. Won't that solve us alot of effort?

Comment: Try having a look at what's available online like https://www.keylemon.com/.  You'll also have to account for lighting, colours or even whether the face has makeup on.  I don't think it is something that can be done easily.  If you can get a library, that would help.

Comment: Thanks @cup for the help!
Let's say I've managed to find a form made on VB that recognizes a picture among set of pictures pre-saved in a certain directory.
How could I upload this form to a webhost. Note: it's not (HTML, PHP) forum, but rather a regular VB application forum.

Comment: No idea whatsoever.  You may have to convert the VB app to a VB command line app and convert the form to a HTML page.  Is this VB6 or VB.net.  If it is VB.net, it may be possible to create it as a web page.  I'm out of my depth here.  Perhaps someone else can tell you how to do that.

Comment: Never mind! I'll try contact people with professional expertise in VB. Thanks alot @cup :)